# Content_tag_for malfunction in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop, tags

I have search results that I need to loop through. Each loop should give me two table rows. The code so far is:

```
<tbody>
  <%= content_tag_for(:tr, @results) do |material| %>
     <tr>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="hide">
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
```

The problem is that I am getting the  with a class and id above the two rows in a separate row. I need these two rows to be wrapped in a  with an id.

e.g.

```
<tr class="X" id="X"></tr>
<tr>
  <td>Some content</td>
  <td>Some content</td>
  <td>Some content</td>
</tr>
<tr class="hide">
  <td>Some content</td>
  <td>Some content</td>
  <td>Some content</td>
</tr>
```

I also have the same problem when I try to use a div_for. In that case I get the divs with the ids all stacked up before the rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you cannot wrap a  in another  using this method. The solution was to write the following:

```
<tbody>
  <%= content_tag_for(:tr, @results) do |material| %>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td>Some content</td>

    <tr class="hide">
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>Some content</td>
      <td>Some content</td>
    </tr>
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The top three 's are wrapped in a  with an id, while the other  is just reproduced verbatim.